# How do I switch the fadeIn/fadeOut effect on an image in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, fadein, fadeout

I've got this working to an 'almost ready' state: http://jsbin.com/icuvit

Can someone show me how to fix this, so if I hover it goes dark, instead of being dark in the first instance. So it goes from **normal -> dark**.

**What do I change in the js code below?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>  
  <div id="mask-div"></div>
  <img id="test-img" src="http://www.google.ca/intl/en_ca/images/logo.gif">
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#mask-div")
    .css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "width": 275,
      "height": 110,
      "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      "display": "block"
    })
    .mouseover( function() {
         $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    })
  ;

  $("#test-img").mouseout( function() {
      $("#mask-div").fadeIn("slow");
  });

});
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

**Many thanks for any pointers.**

Comment: First, reverse the mouseover and mouseout functions. You are specifying the div to start out as visible. So after your mouseout code, you could just add $("#mask-div").hide();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to swap things a bit:

1. Hide the mask initally
2. When the *image* is mouseover-ed, show the mask (when the mask *is not yet* visible, you'll mouseover the image)
3. When the *mask* is mouseout-ed, hide the mask (when the mask *is already* visible, you'll mouseout the mask)

Like: http://jsbin.com/icuvit/3/edit.

```
  $("#mask-div")
    .css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "width": 275,
      "height": 110,
      "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    })
    .mouseout( function() {
      $("#mask-div").fadeOut("slow");
    })
    .hide();

  $("#test-img")
    .mouseover( function() {
      $("#mask-div").fadeIn("slow");
    });
```

And some CSS for the first time:

```
#mask-div {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is fine, except that I'd say `display:none` instead of calling `.hide()` later. Since a div is already block level it will be the same.

Comment: @Sorpigal: Thanks, I didn't see I was still doing `display:block` explicitly.

Comment: Many thanks for this, pimvdb. Only slight downside is, in my real world example, I have multiple images and this causes them all to fade in and out and not just the one hovered over. Is this easy to fix?

Comment: @mcgarriers: It should not since the selectors are using IDs which must be unique. Are you using other selectors perhaps (instead of `#test-img`)?

Comment: Yes, good call. I'm using '.test-img' as I (semantically) I didn't want to use multiple IDs. Is there a way around this using classes? Thanks for your help btw :)

Comment: How exactly is your real-world example constructed? Does each image has its own mask? If so, do they have some kind of connection so that you know which image has which mask?

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/icuvit/4/edit I'm basically just using multiple images, but need each one of them to fade in / out separately.

Comment: @mcgarriers: See my answer for a sample solution, but please don't upvote/accept as it's just pimvdb's all over again.

Comment: Thanks, Sorpigal. I'm still having issues with it. Can I post a final example for you to look at? Realise this has taken a bit longer than expected. Appreciate the patience.

Comment: @mcgarriers: Looking at it, you might want to simply animate the `opacity` property instead of using a mask: http://jsbin.com/icuvit/6/edit. I'm not sure if all browsers support this, though.

Comment: Fantastic!! Many thanks for your patience with this @pimvdb Brilliant help!!

Answer (score 1):

If you actually use some other selectors which results in multiple images you can still use pimvdb's technique in the following way.

```
$('.test-img').each(function(){
    var $img = $(this);

    $("#mask-div")
        .css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "width": 275,
        "height": 110,
        "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    })
    .mouseout( function() {
        $("#mask-div").fadeOut("slow");
    })
    .hide();

    $img.mouseover( function() {
        $("#mask-div").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>  
  <div id="mask-div"></div>
  <img id="test-img" src="http://www.google.ca/intl/en_ca/images/logo.gif">
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#mask-div")
    .css({
      "position": "absolute",
      "width": 275,
      "height": 110,
      "background": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)",
      "display": "none"
    })
    .mouseout( function() {
         $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    })
  ;

  $("#test-img").mouseover( function() {
      $("#mask-div").fadeIn("slow");
  });

});
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```